# Writing snappy compressed data to a hive table

Tags: hadoop, compression, hive, hiveql, snappy

I've created a hive table and now I want to load snappy compressed data into the table. Therefore I did the following:

```
SET mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true;
CREATE TABLE toydata_table (id STRING, value STRING)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";'
```

Then I created as CSV file called toydata.csv that has the following content:

```
A,Value1
B,Value2
C,Value3
```

I compressed this file with snzip ( https://github.com/kubo/snzip ) by doing

```
/usr/local/bin/snzip -t snappy-java toydata.csv
```

which produces `toydata.csv.snappy`. After having done this I returned to the hive cli and loaded the data by `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH "toydata.csv.snappy" INTO TABLE toydata_table;`. But now I want to try to query from that table and get the following error message:

```
hive> select * from toydata_table;
OK
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.checkNativeCodeLoaded(SnappyCodec.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.getDecompressorType(SnappyCodec.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getDecompressor(CodecPool.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

I did the exact same thing with gzip and using gzip works fine. So, why does this part fail?

Comment: Looks you have not installed snappy in your cluster. Which version of your hadoop and hive? You can check here to install snappy for your cluster: https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-snappy/

Comment: I'm using hadoop 2.2 and hive 0.12. I did install all the stuff on my cluster and restarted it. However I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Please install snappy compression codec on your cluster.If you want to confirm whether snappy is installed please find libsnappy.so file in your libraries.
Also you need to **start hive shell with**  **--auxpath** parameter and provide snappy.jar.e.g: hive --auxpath /home/user/snappy1.0.4.1.jar.